# How to setup React+Flux with Flowtype

Tags: reactjs, flux, flowtype

I've found it difficult to setup project that uses React+Flux and Flowtype.

Here is what my `.flowconfig` has:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
static/.*

[options]
module.name_mapper='^core/\(.*\)' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/core/\1'
```

and here is some file

```
/* @flow */
import Dispatcher from 'flux';
import Action from 'core/Action';

const AppDispatcher: Dispatcher<Action> = new Dispatcher();

export default AppDispatcher;
```

But when I try to run `flow check` I'm receiving:

```
core/Dispatcher.js:2
  2: import Dispatcher from 'flux';
                            ^^^^^^ flux. Required module not found
```

Can anyone share their successful experience in setting up the project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you chose to ignore `node_modules`, so flow doesn't see `flux`. You need to remove this line from config or add declarations for `flux`